# HTTParty gem how to rescue errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I would like to rescue errors related to all connection errors using httpparty gem (reset by peer,timeout, etc..)

Something like:

```
  begin
  response = HTTParty.get('http://somewhere.url', http_proxyaddr: proxy_addr,http_proxyport: proxy_port, timeout: 10)
  rescue HTTParty::Error => e
    puts 'HttParty::Error '+ e.message
    retry        
  rescue StandardError => e
   puts 'StandardError '+ e.message
  end
```

Comment: it seems that all errors are rescued as StandardError

Comment: always getting: StandardError 503 "Service Unavailable" or StandardError execution expired

Comment: from [doc](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Error) all exceptions `HTTParty::Error` inherits  from `StandardError` . You can catch what you want.

Comment: if i am getting this right, HTTParty::Error will be raised only for exceptions in: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/commit/6cf4fc7df22c446412a3947da2303caa06163289

Comment: show you code please.

Comment: the code is updated nothing amazing and still getting  StandardError 503 "Service Unavailable" or StandardError execution expired etc..